# How to extract body contents from html file with more than one html tags with jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I need to parse an html file, containing more than one html tags, with jsoup.

I split the document into many html elements and I am able to extract some tags, like title

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8");
Elements el = doc.getElementsByTag("html");
for (Element e : el) {
   writer = new PrintWriter(output);
   writer.println(e.select("title"));
   writer.println(e.select("body"));
   writer.close();
}
```

Output

```
<title>titletext</title>
```

but it seems to ignore the existance of the body tag in every element.

Using `Document.body()` just spits all the contents of the body tags together.

Since I can't get a Document from each Element to use `body()` on, how can I extract the body tag from each Element seperately?

Comment: A file with more than one html tag is not a valid HTML file. It's several HTML pages concatenated (presumably), or worse if they're nested. Why do you deal with such invalid files? Is there no way for the input to be several valid HTML files instead? Otherwise, split the file by yourself, and then analyze each HTML document separately.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you have such a file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph on page 1.</p>
</body>
</html> 

<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph on page 2.</p>
</body>
</html> 

<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title 3</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph on page 3.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

you can split your file at the end of each html part (</html>) and parse each part separately. Example :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class JsoupTest {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {
        String multihtml = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\users\\manna\\desktop\\test.html")));
        String [] htmlParts = multihtml.split("(?<=</html>)");
        Document doc;  

        for(String part : htmlParts){
            doc = Jsoup.parse(part);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("title : "+doc.title());
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(doc.body().outerHtml());
            System.out.println("******************************************");            
        }       
    } 
}
```